# Convertir archivos alojados en servidor Filezilla a base64

Tags: php, ftp, base64

Alguien sabrá como convertir archivos dentro de un servidor ftp, (Filezilla), a "base64", para que luego estos sean visualizados y posiblemente descargados en mi pagina web.

Estoy trabajando con php framework jqwidgets. La idea mía es que de un registro almacenado como "mensaje", pueda tener la facilidad de descargar los archivos que se les adjuntaran. Si es que alguien sabe como, me podría facilitar esto?.

De antemano muchas gracias!.

Comment: Hola @Sebastian
No termino de quedarme claro cual es tu problema. Entiendo que estas usando PHP y JQWidgets que es una libreria para presentacion Javascript.
Basicamente tu interaccion con el servidor FTP debes estar haciendo desde PHP. De que forma? podrias explicarlo un poco mas?

Comment: Hola @Armage, te explicare el proceso, tengo una pagina web de tipo reporteria, dentro de este existe el aparcado mensajes, al hacerle click se despliega una ventana de datos, la cual si se interactua con los datos haciendo doble click el jqxWindow se despliega mostrando el contenido del cuerpo del mensaje, a este cuerpo le agregue un botón de "Descargar Adjuntos", este cumple la función de obviamente descargar los archivos, estos archivos se encuentran dentro de un FTP (filezilla), mi idea es transformalos a base64, para que estos puedan descargarse, pues por php (ftp_get) no pude manipularlo

Comment: Entiendo mejor el problema pero no del todo como intentas solucionarlo. No seria una opcion armar un link al archivo del tipo ftp://servidor/archivo y que sea el navegador el que maneje la descarga del archivo?

Comment: Como podria yo hacer eso @Armage? me pillaste con eso, nisiquiera lo habia imaginado :o

Comment: ftp_get es para poder leer el archivo si necesitas hacer algun tipo de uso de los datos en el archivo. Si solo es para que el usuario se lo descargue podes hacer un link
`ftp://example.com/archivo.ext`
inclusive podes ponerlo en un tag <a href>
`<a href="ftp://example.com/archivo.ext">Descargar</a>`

Comment: Intentare con un href, y te aviso como me va (Y) gracias por darte el tiempo.

Comment: Aun asi tendria que abrir una coneccion con el ftp cierto? @Armage

Comment: no, es solo un link. Si el navegador tiene acceso al server resuelve todo y permite hacer una descarga del archivo. Si es necesario se puede incluir el usuario y pass para login del ftp

Comment: no tienes un ejemplo simple de eso?, necesitaria pass y user para entrar @Armage